# clearing textbox on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask

I am making a basic chat web app. I achieve the functionality and now I am working on the user experience. I am learning JS and jQuery. I want to be able to clear the input box of text as soon as I click within the box to enter in new text/msg. I'm not sure how to do so. Here is what I have so far.

I added this line thinking it would accomplish what I intend but this isn't occurring.

`$("form#my_msg").onclick().val("");`

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // connect
        var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

        // response to browser
        socket.on('response', function(msg) {
            $('#log').append("<br>" + msg.data);
        });

        // send message
        $('form#broadcast').submit(function(event) {
            socket.emit('send message', { data: "<b>" + $('#username').val() + "</b>" + " --> " + $('#my_msg').val()});
            return false;
        });


        $("form#my_msg").onclick().val("");
    });
</script>
<body class="body">
    <form id="broadcast" method="POST" action="#" class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="username" class="form-control">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="my_msg" placeholder="Enter message here...">
        <button type="submit" class="btn tbn-default" style="background-color: #80FF80;">Send</button>   
    </form>

    <h2>Chat</h2>
    <div id="log"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: as simple why do you want to clear the text on click, you can clear it directly as soon as user click send button, once the message is sent you can clear the value using `$("form#my_msg").val("");` The reason here is, suppose i have typed in a partial message, but i lost the focus from textbox, then again on focus the message will be cleared, which is not a correct way to work on a chat web app.

Comment: @Murtaza thank you for bringing this up. You are correct! However I added this piece of code within my <script> tags and tested it out and nothing happens =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to my comment to this question!

Clearing the textbox on every focus or click is not a good idea for a chat web app.

Explain the details in comment saying why we should not follow clearing a text field on focus in such scenario.

You can script to clear the text on submit after calling you ajax call to send the message to the receiver.

```
 // send message
        $('form#broadcast').submit(function(event) {
            socket.emit('send message', { data: "<b>" + $('#username').val() + "</b>" + " --> " + $('#my_msg').val()});
            $("#my_msg").val("");
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
$("#my_msg").val("");
```

or

```
$( "#my_msg" ).focusin(function() {
  $( this ).val("");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMmPs/)

**Change** : Selector should be `$('form #my_msg')`. `<input>` - `#my_msg` is the child of `<form>` element.

---

Following is the correct syntax for using `click` handler. **[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

```
$("form #my_msg").on('click',function(){
    $(this).val('');
})
```

or javascript way

```
$("form #my_msg").on('click',function(){
    this.value = '';
})
```

*Suggestion* : Try `focus` event instead of the click.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use

```
<input type="text" id="my_msg" onClick="this.value=''">
```

or

```
$("form#my_msg")..val("");
```

or

```
document.getElementById("my_msg").value="";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("form#my_msg").on('focus', function(){
         $(this).val('');
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/kdEV8/

Answer (score 1):

try this bro

```
 $("#my_msg").on("click", function(){
     this.value = "";
 });
```

Comment: hey this works but another mentioned how this isn;t how a chat app works. Instead I should clear the text after i've clicked send. I tried to change your code youve given me a bit but im sorta suck. If you can do thsi I'll accept the answer

Comment: after clicking the send button, then it will clear the textbox right?